# JQuery - How to append new functions to existing event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've came across this use case: Multiple template files have their own JavaScript code to handle browser resize. I wish that, as rendered result, all the templates will handle browser resize event using the JavaScript defined in each of the templates (Similar to the Event Handler feature of C#)

For example:

```
header.jsp - alert('foo') when browser resizes

body.jsp - alert('bar') when browser resizes

When header/body.jsp are rendered into one page:

alert('foo') then alert('bar') when browser resizes.
```

So far I don't see how JQuery can support this use case. Is my idea feasible?

Thank you!

Comment: `jsp`? as in java server pages? so you want to refetch header/body from server on every resize?

Comment: my fault, so i didn't explain clearly.. edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is .js fileending and not .jsp.

But the event you must listen is the resize event. In JQuery you can use this:

```
$(document).resize(function() {
    //whatever
    alert('foo');
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('resize', function() {
    //whatever
    alert('bar');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already done that, and the problem is: in t1.jsp, the function passed to $(document).resize(func) is overwritten by $(document).resize(func2) in t2.jsp. I would like both func and func2 to run when resize.

Comment: That's strange. I myself use in different .js files the resize eventhandler and it works.

Comment: that may indicate other issue with my html, I will check other places. thank you for your help